# What is the simplified value of $(\tan15)(\tan30)(\tan45)(\tan60)(\tan75)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

What is the simplified value of $(\tan15)(\tan30)(\tan45)(\tan60)(\tan75)$

I am trying to find this value without the use of a calculator but there are certain values I do not know like $(\tan15)$ and $(\tan75)$

Can someone give me any advice?

Comment: $$\tan(90^\circ-x)=\cot x=\dfrac1{\tan x}$$

Comment: Are you sure you want $\tan 15$ and not $\tan 15^\circ$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using $\tan(90^0-x)=\cot(x)$

Observe that $\tan75^0=\tan(90^0-15^0)=\cot(15^0)$

And $\tan60^0=\tan(90^0-30^0)=\cot(30^0)$

So we have

$\tan15^0\cdot \tan30^0 \cdot \tan45^0 \cdot \cot30^0 \cdot \cot15^0 =\tan45^0=1$

Comment: Note that you can make better degree symbols with `^{\circ}`.

Comment: Got it . Will use hereafter

Answer (score 3):

$\tan 75^{\circ}=\cot 15^{\circ}$ ...and so on..

Hence  value $=1$.

Comment: @ Joel Reyes Noche) Calculate it in degree NOT in radian..

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to solve is that when we have two values of tan in multiplication and their angles sum up 90 then their multiplication is always 1 eg tan70tan20=1 so answer is 1.